# How to remove description tab and make additional info open by default

Tags: tabs

I am trying to remove the product description tab entirely, and I would like the Additional info tab to be opened by default.  Previous answers to this question are for different versions of magento, and the catalog.xml file seems to have changed.  Currently using 1.9.  I've looked through all the template files and can't find anywhere to get rid of description and add the active class to additional into, any ideas?

Comment: Your're using default theme I assume?

Comment: No, I'm using the shopper theme by queldorei

Answer (score 2):

To Remove product description tab entirely, comment following code from `\app\design\frontend\shopper\default\layout\local.xml`

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ><alias>description_tabbed</alias><title>Details</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
```

Which is around line number 217.

Once commented you will be able to load Additional info tab by default.

Best Of Luck !!!!

Comment: does ur path right